# Why is Vue displaying both alternatives of a v-if condition?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I am somehow ending up with Vue displaying *both* variants of a `v-if` condtion, when it should be displaying only one.

The layout starts like this:

[image]

and after a drag operation looks like this, with the extra component ( a `vuetify` `v-chip`) being pushed into a new row because there isn't enough room (there should be only 5 in a row):

[image]

I have checked the contents of the grid row that contains the data for these chips and confirmed that, after the drag, it still has only five columns, so there should be just 5 chips. The duplicated chip (the first 'A', the one that should not be there) has the `outlined` variant and the correct one (the blue 'A') does not - this is the correct result of dragging the original outlined 'A' chip out of the grid. The Vue template section is:

```
<v-container id="startgrid" style="max-width: 240px; height: 250px; position: relative;">
  <v-row v-for="(row,r) in startGrid" >
    <template v-for="(chip,c) in row" :key="chip.id" >
        <v-chip v-if="!chip.used" size="x-large" variant="outlined" class="copyable changeclass"
            @dropped="drop"
            @swapped="swap"
            :data-keep-row = r
            :data-keep-col = c
            :data-letter = chip.name
            :id=idString(0,r,c)
            > {{ chip.name }}
        </v-chip>
        <v-chip v-else size="x-large" 
            :data-letter = chip.name
            :id=idString(0,r,c)
            color="blue"
            > {{ chip.name }}
        </v-chip>
    </template>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

To confirm that I really am seeing *both* conditions of the `v-if`, I temporarily added the row and column numbers to the text of the blue variant but not to the outlined one, the result being (for a different letter being dragged):

[image]

Also (although not shown here) I temporarily added the length of the grid row to the chip name, to see how long 'Vue' thought it was when it was actually rendered. It was 5.

Looking at the elements in the browser debugger confirms what I am seeing, i.e. an extra component with opposing styles.

The drag/drop code manipulating the components (the code that provides the `dropped` and `swapped` events) is too involved to replicate here, so I am just wondering what *sort of* error might lead to this? How can `chip.used` (the conditional value) be both true and false at the same time?

---

Edit

A suggested answer is that the `:key` values may be duplicated. I have checked these and they are all defined uniquely - 1 to 25 for each cell of the 5 x 5 grid. Having said that, is there a way I can view these `:key` values for each component in a browser inspector? I can see the element id's but not any `:key` values. More specifically, if I am copying/replacing an element (see code below), do I need to reset the `:key`? If so, how?

---

I have also been asked to provide a reproducible example. Currently there are hundreds of code lines leading to this error, but I will try to arrange something smaller. In the meantime, the specific lines causing it are something like this:

```
function copyObject(source,dest) {

  const parent2 = dest.parentNode;
  const parent1 = source.parentNode;
  const nextSib = source.nextSibling;

  if (parent1 === null || parent2 === null)
    throw 'null parent(s) in copying element'

  // a copy needed to replace the one being copied and moved
  const copyElement = source.cloneNode(true);

  // move to new grid
  parent2.replaceChild(source,dest);
  // replaceChild() removes original , so replace the original with the copy
  parent1.insertBefore(copyElement.el,nextSib);
}
```

Comment: Might have to do with doing manual DOM manipulation. You should ***not*** do that. Change the data source and let Vue handle DOM updates.

Comment: @tao, you may have a point. I am writing a drag'n'drop library which I had hoped would work with both Vue and plain JS - hence the DOM manipulation. Maybe not a good idea :(

Comment: No, not a good idea. In terms of updating DOM in a `v-for` all you need to do is update the data source. Vue takes care of updating the appropriate DOM elements and it's quite smart about it (e.g: performant). When updating DOM yourself inside a Vue app you're a driver pushing your car to the destination. Most importantly, Vue does not check the DOM it generated for updates. It only listens to changes in data layer, so your mods will get lost (overwritten) on next data change, when Vue updates DOM, if you modified any DOM elements Vue updates.

Comment: You were asking for a way to see the key values - are you already using Vue devtools? (See: [Vue devtools for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd))

Comment: @PeterKrebs, how come I've been using Vue for 3 months and nobody told me about this yet??

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, your `:key` is not unique, leading to Vue being unable to detect which nodes to remove. Here is a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UctOwzAQ/JVRLk2QacPrUlIkjhw4wqXpwSTbNqpjR7ZTqQr5d9YOBE5crH3Nzux4SJ67bnnuKVknhats03k48n33VOqm7Yz1GGBpL2D0q+m1pzqEb7qdEozYW9NiwSsWpa6Mdh6q4WcTYOn2RtyKO3EvHnbZT9vqmrtphs0TXqU/Lq3UtWm5cBWhy7NUPS0V6YM/4hN5qWfydIKxxBdOLU9+V4ZS4y/adaqpKGWuNBO4YfJ/2rkIotKMp0aB2zzPQ1isJkPYCk48tZ2SnjgD3sMSB2kJvWMXpMOJLk6gNuT0wsPLE0EZfQDLbhTqPhAyHJHfoZIM/C3X0KYmtw7Li7o5RxZgi5kX5+u9sZsycWh0PKVMsGbWUCqTCCh94TrJgfMXRdyojDJ2jQ+mfOSZYXAjH8iH8VREFKv5LuyQxr+MRNGwYjVJmVUNQyAeR6T8uWRJV8QmWHnJplFEFezcvDUZvwAA2c1f) reproducing the behavior.

Could this be your issue?

Comment: thanks yet again for your input. A great playground demo! But I don't think the `:key` values are at fault in my code - see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

@Tao's suggestion was in fact the answer. It is incorrect to try to manipulate the DOM when using Vue (or, I suppose , other reactive-type libraries).
All I needed to do was to ignore the final DOM manipulation of my drag/drop library:

```
function copyObject(source,dest) {

  if (Draggable.options.reactive)
    // nothing to do here
        return;

  const parent2 = dest.parentNode;
  const parent1 = source.parentNode;
  const nextSib = source.nextSibling;
  .....
  .....
}
```

plus a simple change afterwards to copy the new images back into the data source, ready for Vue to render.

```
trackGrid[toRow][toCol].type = fromType;
trackGrid[toRow][toCol].content = cellImage(fromType);
```

This is now so much more straightforward than trying to move the elements themselves.
I am still using DOM manipulation for temporary changes (e.g. moving an copy image across the screen during a drag) so most of the rest of my library remains intact, and can still be used both for Vue and for plain JS.

Plus a bonus, from a comment I also learned about [vue DevTools for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) - it looks great! Why didn't I find it sooner?